# Algebra formed by operators and Kuratowski's theorem

Tags: general-topology

I have been reading the paper "D. Sherman, Variations on Kuratowski's 14-set theorem, Amer. Math. Monthly 117 (2010), no. 2, 113-123" recently. Kuratowski Closure complement theorem  states that:
 Let $ A \subseteq X$ be a subset of a topological space. The number of distinct
sets which can be obtained from E by successively taking closures and complements
(in any order) is at most 14. Moreover, there are subsets of the Euclidean line
for which 14 is attained.
 The present paper discusses its variations by introducing operations like closure, interior, complement, intersection, union where the corresponding operators are denoted by $\{c, i, k , \vee, \wedge \}$.
The main aim of the author is to apply different operations from this set   repeatedly on a subset of a topological space and obtain various bounds. 
At several places the author uses the term  $\textbf{algebra}$ generated by the topological operations. I have gone through the definition of algebra here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra. But I can't relate it to the algebra used by the author in this context. If anyone can just help me with this concept?

I have one more question in context to the above mentioned paper. While giving the proofs of the variations of Kuratowski Clsoure complement Theorem with the set of operators $\{c,i,\wedge\}$ or $\{c,i,\wedge, \vee\}$, the author insists on an assumption that topological space contains a copy of $\mathbb{R}$. I do not find any particular use of this assumption in any of these proofs. My question is  if we do not take this assumption can't the proofs just follow? May be  I am not getting it. It would be great if anyone could just help me with this?

Comment: Sherman uses his assumption that the space contains a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ in the very same sentence: "Assuming $X$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{R}$, the order structure of $(k,i)$ is as shown in Figure 1 [that is, $X$ contains subsets that generate 14 sets under $k$ and $i$]."  This is a necessary starting point when you are attempting to find the maximum possible number of subsets that can be generated from one subset under an expanded collection of operations that includes $k$ and $i$.

Comment: @mathematrucker so this means on which ever space $X$ we start working with ( for applying closures, interiors and intersections on its subsets) must contain a 14-set ( that is, those sets which give exactly 14 sets on applying closure and complement repeatedly) ? I suppose this is necessary because if these 14 operators are distinct (or equivalently 7 operators using closure and interior ) then only it is meaningful to  take further operations like intersections, unions ( correspondingly meet or join) etc. Hope I am getting it right ? but does that 14-set necessarily have to be $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: the main thing to keep in mind here is the $\mathbb R$ assumption is completely harmless for the purpose at hand.  All the author is doing is putting together a little workshop for finding the theoretical maximum.  The reason he puts in a copy of $\mathbb R$ is to get Kuratowski 14-sets to work with.  Other spaces would have sufficed too, but $\mathbb R$ is standard so he chose $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @mathematrucker Thanks for your input. Do you have any useful comments on the first part of the question, that is, the usage of the term  algebra throughout the paper (or may be closure algebras referred towards the end of the paper)

Comment: see my answer below (it was too long to post as a comment so I posted it as an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sherman's use of the word *algebra* suppresses the underlying set (on which there is a collection of operations) and refers only to the collection of operations on the underlying set.  More specifically, whenever you see the word *algebra* in Sherman's paper, you can take it to mean "subset of ${\rm End}({\cal P}(X))$" where $X$ is an arbitrary set, ${\cal P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$, and ${\rm End}({\cal P}(X))$ is the set of operations from ${\cal P}(X)$ to itself.

Note that the underlying set here is ${\cal P}(X)$.  Thus with regard to Sherman's paper anyway, Lord_Farin's comments are misleading on two counts:

(1) They allow the underlying set to be *any subset of* ${\cal P}(X)$, whereas Sherman's paper always assumes the underlying set is ${\cal P}(X)$ itself.

(2) Instead of suppressing the underlying set (as Sherman does), Lord_Farin suppresses the operations and uses the word *algebra* to refer to the underlying set.

In Sections 1-4 Sherman explicitly means "subset of ${\rm End}({\cal P}(X))$" when he uses the word *algebra*; in the rest of the paper he essentially means this same thing, as this critically important paragraph in Section 5 confirms:

"The key observation is that any closure algebra can be identified with a Boolean sublattice of some ${\cal P}(X)$, where $X$ is a topological space and $k$ becomes the associated closure operator [**10**, Theorem 2.4]. Thus Question 1.3 asks about the cardinalities of subalgebras of $\cal F$ in which only some of $\{I,i,k,c,\wedge,\vee\}$ can be used."

Comment: so in the context of your answer, we can say for the set of operations generated by, say, closure($c$), interior($i$) and meet($\wedge$),(defined on P(X)) given as : $\mathcal{A}= \{id,i,ici,ic,ci,cic,c, id \wedge ici,id \wedge ic,id \wedge ci,id \wedge cic,ic \wedge ci,ic \wedge ci \wedge id\}$ is an algebra (being subset of $End(P(X))$) which is closed under the operations $c,i,\wedge$ (or compositions may be). The algebra being $\mathcal{A}$ with underlying set (that is, the set on which these operations are defined) being $P(X)$ in this case?

Comment: @User23 Yes that is correct, both in the context of my answer and in the context of Sherman's paper.  See my list of references at http://www.mathematrucker.com/mathtransit/cornucopia.php for more literature on the Kuratowski closure-complement theorem and related subjects.

Answer (score 1):

It is used in the sense of [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra). Quoting wikipedia

> In universal algebra, an algebra (or algebraic structure) is a set A
>   together with a collection of operations on A.

Comment: You might want to add that the set $A$ here is not the subset $A \subseteq X$ but rather some set of sets $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$.

Comment: @lord-farin You are perfectly right. The letter $A$ is unfortunate in the context of this question.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I meant to say we are considering a subset A of a topological space X. I did not get what are you trying to convey?

Comment: @User23 That the algebra $A$ and the subset $A$ are not the same thing. The algebra $A$ consists of subsets of $X$ (for otherwise it is hard to intersect them, take complements, etc.).

Comment: @ J.-E Pin so this means we are here referring to just the property  that the resulting algebraic structure generated is  closed with respect to the operators in consideration ?

Comment: @Lord_Farin I get it the resulting sets generated after applying various operations are subsets of power set of space $X$.